# laravel eloquent orm view

Tags: php, laravel

My ultimate goal is to print the contents of a table in a database to a table in HTML  using Laravel's ORM.

Beyond that I know how to configure the database file, but is there any other things i need to configure.

From my understanding I need three files. Do i need to make a controller? If so how does that work?

1. Item Class
2. Route.php
3. views.php

Here is what I have so far

Item.php

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Item extends Model {
    protected $table = 'items';
    protected $primaryKey = 'item_id';
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('item_id', 'item_name', 'item_cost');
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
<?php
Route::get('Product', function()
{
    $products = \App\items::all();   
    return view('Items', $items);
});
```

and I have no idea how to create a view in HTML.

I know I'm completely off at this point, but I've read the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0) and I am still completely lost when they reference things like URI and have URL in the same sentence without defining or even linking to it elsewhere in the documentation.

Comment: URI and URL are very common terms. Just search for such things online. In this particular case, this should help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier

Comment: I know what both of them mean. but their usage of URI and URL in reference to what they're trying to explain is a little confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you have declared your `Eloquent ORM` like this:

```
class Item extends Model {
    // ...
}
```

But you are using that `model/class` like this:

```
$products = \App\items::all();
```

In this case, `\App\items` doesn't exist, it should be:

```
$items = \App\Item::all(); // <-- Item not items
return view('items', $items); // <-- $items not $products
```

You asked: `Do i need to make a controller?`

In this case, no, it'll work fine with the `anonymous` function but using a `Controller` is better for many reasons.

**Update:**

Create a view in `resources/views` as `items.blade.php` and you can print out the items through a `foreach` loop. [Check the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views).

Comment: Thank you! how do I get this to display in a php or html page?

Comment: Thank you, I just don't understand how I open a blade file? What would I put in my browser to display everything?